# Is there posibility to insert binary file as resource to VS project with cmake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, cmake, resources

I try to build exe which will be show static bmp image compiled into exe. But I can't to do this because preprocessor doesn't find definition of the file in follow winapi code:

```
case WM_PAINT :
        hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &PaintStruct);
        hBitmap = LoadImage(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SPLASH), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(number1)
set (R_DIR "/res")
set(CMAKE_MFC_FLAG 1)
add_executable(main WIN32 src/main.cpp res/r.rc)
set_target_properties(main PROPERTIES RESOURCE /res/splash.bmp)
```

res.rc:

```
IDI_SPLASH  BITMAP  "sample.bmp"
```

In Visual Studio Resource Viewer bmp file is opened, but named with double quotas ("IDI_SPLASH").

P.s. sorry, but English isn't my native language

Comment: The `IDI_SPLASH` identifier doesn't just magically appear. You are going to have to defined it yourself (e.g. `#define IDI_SPLASH 42`). This is commonly done in a header file that both your source code and the resource script include.

Comment: Starting a path with `/` seems weird. Usually this means you speficy a absolute path starting at the file system root which in this case would be something like `C:/res/splash.bmp`; haven't worked with `RESOURCE` yet, so I cannot tell you, if it's any different with this property.

Comment: @fab *"Usually this means ..."* - I don't know, what you would attribute as "usual*, but on Windows, `/` doesn't mean anything. *"the file system root"* - What does that even mean, on Windows? This question is about CMake, Windows resource scripts, and Microsoft's compiler and linker. I doubt that anything you provided has any bearing on those tools.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you very much! I'm very appreciate for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to IInspectable answer I've added resource.h with:

```
#define IDI_SPLASH 101 //or other number id.
```

This header I've included in source file (.cpp) and resource.rc. Include command in the resource file is same as in the source file:

```
#include "resource.h"
IDI_SPLASH  BITMAP  "sample.bmp"
```

It works :)